SQLite Expression - name space conflict with Xcode 16/iOS 18
When you will update Xcode 15 to Xcode 16, you will get many errors using SQLite.swift library.
For example: Missing argument label 'value:' in call etc, etc.
How to fix them?

How to fix it?
Just add typealias Expression = SQLite.Expression as a class attribute. It worked perfectly fine for me. Other solutions could be to import SQLite.Expression if it can work for your case.
References:
https://github.com/stephencelis/SQLite.swift/issues/1269
https://github.com/stephencelis/SQLite.swift/issues/1277

Xcode 15
Expression<String>("id")

Xcode 16
SQLite.Expression<String>("id")


This is the right answer. However, a note for folks arriving from a search engine: I first went along with Xcode's recommendation and added value: to each Expression argument instead of the SQLite. qualifier. That resulted in these errors when I used my Int column: Referencing operator function '==' on 'BinaryInteger' requires that 'Expression<String>' conform to 'BinaryInteger'
